# orWhereHas cancelling out my other Where condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I am trying to do a query that is filtered by a date range. The issue is I need to do a orWhereHas query as well which currently is not obeying the my whereBetween query.

So I have 2 tables Promos and Member_Promo. To get the upcoming promos for a user I use a function like `Auth::user()->upcomingPromos('ytd')`. The function looks like:

```
public function upcomingPromos($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'ytd':
                $range = [Carbon::today(), Carbon::now()->endOfYear()];
                break;

            case 'mtd':
                $range = [Carbon::today(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()];
                break;
        }


        return Promo::where('owner_id', $this->id)
            ->whereBetween('date', $range)
            ->orWhereHas('members', function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', $this->id);
            })
            ->oldest('date')
            ->get();
    }
```

What I want the end result to be is all promos between the date ranges where the user is either:

- a.) the owner (promo table with owner_id)
- b.) a member (members_promo table with user_id).

  So the list would be all there promos they are a part of between a date range.

The promo table has the `owner_id` and `date` I search by. The `members_promo` table is just a pivot with `user_id` and `promo_id`. The issue stems from the orWhereHas is not limiting that query by the date range. So if a user is a member of a promo that is not in that range it still returns when it should not.

Comment: I think you'll want to nest your `whereBetween` and `orWhereHas` within a `where(function($query) { })` call.

Comment: The `whereBetween` is looking for a date column that is not on the pivot table so not sure how to do that. `$query->whereBetween('date', $range)` wont work I imagine since that column doesnt exist on that table

Comment: Actually it worked that way? I guess I just assumed it wouldnt

Comment: Laravel's pretty smart about these things. :-) If that resolved your issue, let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Smarter than me! It did. I just had to add use ( $range ) and pass in the whereBetween

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `get()` with `toSql()` is really handy for debugging this sort of query issue - it'll show you the SQL that's getting rendered and executed by your query builder calls.

In your case, wrapping the two parameters you want to `OR` together in a `where(function($query) { })` does the trick. Under the hood, this puts the two conditions in side parentheses in the resulting query.

```
return Promo::where('owner_id', $this->id)
    ->where(function($q) use ($range) {
        $q->whereBetween('date', $range)
            ->orWhereHas('members', function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', $this->id);
            });
    })
    ->oldest('date')
    ->get();
```